# How to change options for Summernote after it is initialized?

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, summernote

I have multiple summernote editors in a page, I want to change their options after they are initialized.

For example if they are initialized with this options:

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
    option1: value1,
    option2: value2
});
```

I want to change it to:

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
    option1: anotherValue
});
```

Is it possible without editing the first code and without loosing other options, I need to change/update one special option and keep other options untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.summernote:not(:first-child)').summernote({
   option: anotherValue,
   ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried this before, but it broke other options, I need to change/update one special option and keep other options untouched.

Comment: OK, I will add it soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can give them unique id's to be able to figure out which one to edit. But unfortunately, there's no redraw option for summernote itself and changing or adding options once it was initialized doesn't work.

**Option 1:** Destroy and reinitialize the note using the destroy method and then re-initializing it.

*Note, You'll probably need to remember to save the code value if any text is already entered. As for the options, recommend saving it as an array outside the initialization so you can reuse it later when you need to change a setting.*

```
let summernoteOptions = {
    option1: value1,
    option2: value2
}

$('.summernote').summernote(summernoteOptions);

$('#note2 .summernote').summernote('destroy');

summernoteOptions.option1 = anotherValue;

$('#note2 .summernote').summernote(summernoteOptions);
```

**Option 2:** Is a little more time consuming, but it involves looking at the output html structure and modifying the dom objects directly.

Here's an example that sets colors for the row palette of the background color of all notes loaded on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    var palette = ['#346cb0', '#0179a8', '#00a28a', '#f7c46c', '#b76ba3', '#5f4b8b', '#b76ba3', '#ec935e'];

    Array.from($('#backColorPalette .note-color-palette .note-color-row')).forEach(function(item, index, arr) {
        Array.from(item.children).forEach(function(item, index, arr) {
            arr[index].ariaLabel = palette[index];
            arr[index].style['background-color'] = palette[index];
            arr[index].dataset.originalTitle  = palette[index];
            arr[index].dataset.value  = palette[index];
        });
    });
});
```